# disappear of the text written in the text field after pressing done

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am using a text field in my app to write comments, when the user type a text and press a button the text should be written to the database. However, I have a problem which is when I write the text then press done or return from the keyboard, the text disappear then there is no comment to be added. Is there any idea to save the value of the text in the text field even after pressing done or return?

Comment: use a `TextEditingController` and remember to initialise it somewhere other than build method.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why your input is disappearing but you can use a `TextEditingController` and pass that controller to a `TextField`.
Then access the value of the `TextField` using `controller.text` .

Here is a little example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  String databaseText;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            onEditingComplete: () {
              databaseText = controller.text;
              print(databaseText);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this issue happen because the TextEditingController is rebuilt after you add your text. for me I used static controller to solve this problem.

```
  static TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
```

and I highly recommend reading [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29542)

Answer (score 0):

```
String _text;
final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

Form(
    key: formKey,
    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        autocorrect: false,
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Text:"),
        onSaved: (str) => _text = str,
      )
    ]));
```

Then just pass your _text variable inside your paramater as your key value.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifing contentPadding in InputDecoration. For example:

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2, vertical: 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

The corresponding Flutter bug report is [#29542: "Text getting cleared when using TextEditingController AND StreamBuilder"](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29542).

There, user [bizz84 commented](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29542#issuecomment-473847317), asking:

> So the reason that this works with `StatefulWidget` is that the state is retained even across rebuilds, so I can use it to hold my `TextEditingController`s.
>
> Is this correct?

And [rrousselGit replied](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29542#issuecomment-473848355):

> Exactly :-)
>
> Generally speaking, don't create anything but primitives in a StatelessWidget/InheritedWIdget. For everything else, you'll need a State

So, this appears to be the official answer: if you are creating anything other than primitives, you will need a State.